# Not able to find saas on osx

Tags: ruby, sass, rubygems

I installed saas using gem. It got installed successfully.

```
Fetching: saas-0.1.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed saas-0.1.1
Parsing documentation for saas-0.1.1
Installing ri documentation for saas-0.1.1
1 gem installed
```

But now when i do saas -v, i get:

```
-bash: saas: command not found
```

There are tons of question regarding the same but nothing works for me.

gem env gives this output:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.0.14
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2014-05-08 patchlevel 481) [universal.x86_64-darwin14]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/gaurav/.gem
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/gaurav/.gem/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - universal-darwin-14
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/gaurav/.gem
     - /Users/gaurav/.gem/ruby/2.0.0
     - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0
     - /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
```

The bin and ruby directory is not present in /Users/gaurav/.gem/.

Comment: The saas gem doesn't have any executables. What were you expecting to happen.

Comment: Shouldn't it create an executable for Sass and place it in the bin so that I can run Sass commands. If not how do I run Sass now?

Comment: You haven't installed sass. You've installed saas